# manipulating ShellItemArray

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

How can I remove items from a given ShellItemArray? or alternatively, create a new ShellItemArray from specific shell items of the current array?
Non of the SHCreateShellItemArray*** functions help me in that (there is one function named SHCreateShellItemArrayFromShellItem, but it creates an array from single shell item, not a few)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify an existing array without directly messing with the object in memory so your best bet is probably to create a new array with [SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can probably use [SHGetIDListFromObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) while building the pidl array.